# multiple useless mysql queri by graphql in strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

this is my simple query:

```
{
  metas(limit: 1){
          id
        }
 }
```

I monitored the mysql server queries and I saw it converted to some useless queries :

> select `metas`.* from `metas` order by `created_at` asc, `user` desc
>   limit 1
>
> select distinct `articles`.*,
>   `articles_metas__metas_articles`.`meta_id` as `_pivot_meta_id`,
>   `articles_metas__metas_articles`.`article_id` as `_pivot_article_id`
>   from `articles` inner join `articles_metas__metas_articles` on
>   `articles_metas__metas_articles`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` where
>   `articles_metas__metas_articles`.`meta_id` in (25)

and ....

each article has some meta .  but I want only meta id!!!!!

Comment: Is there a question here? :P

Answer (score 0):

it s a bug in strapi, the complete issue submited to strapi git:
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5363

alexandrebodin:

> Blockquote

Right now you should use a manyWay relation (unidirectional relation to avoid the issue).
This is due to autopopulation being used even if not necessary.

Hopefully we can address this soon.

> Blockquote